# 'Whenever' with future time clause

Tags: grammar, future-time

Question is simple..

My friend asked me *'When will you sleep?'*

My answer should be..

'*Whenever I'll feel sleepy.*'
Or
'*Whenever I feel sleepy.*'

Comment: We don't use the future tense in this case, because we're not talking about the future, we're talking about a hypothetical or general truth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Present Simple is used as a condition. Why not 'will'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/307707/the-present-simple-is-used-as-a-condition-why-not-will)

Comment: I *will* go to bed when/if/whenever I *feel* sleepy.

Comment: Er, no, @stangdon, in the question as posed, they _are_ talking about the future, not about a general truth. That is not why we don't use the modal expression after _whenever_.